# How can I issue parallel commands to remote nodes with different arguments?

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-server

I need to execute an application in parallel on multiple Ubuntu-Linux servers while supplying different arguments for different servers. I tried to google it, but could not get to the possible solution. I even experimented with ssh/pdsh/parallel, but without success.

To explain the scenario further, here is a non-working example (with pdsh) where script.sh should be executed on all 3 servers in parallel but with different arguments. FYI, I already have public/private ssh-key (password-free login) in place.

**$ pdsh -w server1,server2,server3 -l username script.sh args**
where args should be 1 for server1, 2 for server2 etc.

I would appreciate if someone can help me achieve this, either using pdsh or some other tool available in Ubuntu. Thanks for your help.

Regards 
Sachin

Comment: Why not start three different commands in the background?

Comment: Wouldn't it mean running three pdsh commands (in background) one after other using a script? I was assuming that using a system supplied approach might have less time lag between all invocations as compared to script created for same job. Correct me if my assumptions are wrong. Thank you for your quick reply.

Comment: Yes, your assumption isn't *quite* correct.  While issuing the three requests in the background wouldn't cause those to start at the same *exact* instance, those would still start at the same time for all practical purposes.

Comment: I will surely try this approach. As long as it can guarantee start of application on around 20-30 servers within a window of 2-4 seconds, it would work for me.

Comment: Yes, it'd work.  To be clear, say: `pdsh -w server1 -l username script.sh args1 &; pdsh -w server2 -l username script.sh args2 &; ...`

Answer (score 1):

I've done similar things using `cssh` in the past, but I don't see why `pdsh` wouldn't work with the same approach (although I've never used it).

My assumption is that you have an interactive session running simultaneously on all systems *and* you are able to create new environment variables in each session.  If `pdsh` doesn't allow this, `cssh` *does*.

Before starting your script, set an environment variable based on the hostname.

```
ARG=$( case $(hostname) in server1) echo 1;; server2) echo 2;; server3) echo 3;; esac )
script.sh $ARG
```

Assuming the number you want is encoded in your hostname (as suggested in your question), you can simplify it like this:

```
script.sh ${HOSTNAME#server}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any special tools - ssh and bash are sufficient. If you want to add more servers, all you need to do is add them to the arrays near the top. Be careful with the spaces in the sample code below. Use multiple argument arrays if you have multiple arguments. An ssh config file allows per host user names.

```
`#!/bin/bash
servers=( server1 server2 server3 )
args=( args1 args2 args3 )
count=${#servers[@]}
k=0
while ((k<count))
do
  ssh -l username ${servers[k]} 'script ${args[k]}' &
  ((k++))
done`
```